# How to gather input from an alert when a window is closed to determine whether to save in an objective-c mac application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, input

I made it so that in an objective-c mac application developed in Xcode, an alert would appear asking the user whether they wish to save when they try and close the main window. How would I gather the user's input from this alert?

I know you can use this code to generate an alert with various options and text:

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Save and Quit"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Quit"];
[alert setMessageText:@"Would you like to save before you quit?"];
[alert setInformativeText:@"You are about to quit. Would you like to save your progress?"];
[alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:[self window] modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(null) contextInfo:nil];
```

And I know that you can use the

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
```

method to run when the main window is closed, but how would I gather the user's input from this alert?

Comment: I think the documentation for beginSheetModealForWindow might contain the answer: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSAlert](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Dialog/Tasks/UsingAlerts.html) panels aren't really meant for gathering info but for alerting the user of some sort of state and then recording which button they pressed in response.

What I've had to do in the past is to create my own window/xib with it's window controller, textviews, and selectors and manage it all from there.

On the other hand if you were just talking about getting the state of which button was pressed, as shown from the link, something like this would work:

```
if ([alert runModal] == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
    // OK clicked, delete the record
    [self deleteRecord:currentRec];
}
```